# Using django-email-login for authentication but disabling email verification

Tags: django, email, authentication

Regarding the django-email-login app, how do i get it not to require email verification by the user? I find that this extra activity that the user has to go through by logging into their email account to validate their email could reduce signups.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to this django-email-login: https://bitbucket.org/jokull/django-email-login/src, and not my django-email-login: https://bitbucket.org/tino/django-email-login/overview, (sorry for the confusion, I hadn't seen his repo until I bumped into this question and started searching) as I don't do any signup.

However I would like to advice you that you might be more likely to get an answer when you post your question as an issue on bitbucket, as there people that use the app will actually see it.

From a quick look at the code I would say you need to write your own RegistrationBackend, one that doesn't need validation. The backend used in jokull's code is actually the one from django-registration, so you should take that as an example.